# Pick one contact detail using intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to get a contact details from my app. So what I have done is using Intent I direct my app to device contact. From there I want to select one contact detail including phone number, mail id, and whatever the details available. Is it possible?

The Intent I used is

```java
Intent read1=new Intent();
read1.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
read1.setData(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivity(read1);
```

Comment: @segi I want fetch the contact details...

Comment: on click of that particular contact??

Comment: Am getting the contact name and number from this code

Comment: then you have to change your code.. mostly like below answer..

Comment: Yeah I had done it and got result too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used this way.

**in your onClick where to open contact list.**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
   startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
        if (0 == reqCode) {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    System.out.println("in on ActivityResult");
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                        String hasPhone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                        if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                            null,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                                    + " = " + id, null, null);
                            phones.moveToFirst();
                            cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                            name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            //here you can find out all the thing.
                            System.out.println("NAME:"+name);
                            etFirst.setText(cNumber);
                    }
                    }
                }
            }

    }
```

**Permissions**

Add a permission to read contacts data to your application manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

If you find any trouble then let me know.enjoy..